# Orbital rotation of the camera with two fingers in a unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

for several days I haven't been able to figure it out. You need to make the camera rotate around a certain object using two fingers on the phone. I kind of twirl my fingers in a circle and it should spin.
I found a solution, but the camera for some reason very often twitches during rotation and sometimes turns very strongly, with a little movement. How I can do it better?

```
public void Execute()
    {
        if (_officeModel.Camera.orthographic) return;

        _camera = _officeModel.Camera.transform;

        var pos1 = CreateRaycast(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        var pos2 = CreateRaycast(Input.GetTouch(1).position);
        var pos1b = CreateRaycast(Input.GetTouch(0).position - Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition);
        var pos2b = CreateRaycast(Input.GetTouch(1).position - Input.GetTouch(1).deltaPosition);

        var screenCenter = _officeModel.SelectedObject == null ? CreateRaycast(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0)) : _officeModel.SelectedObject.transform.position; //Get screen center transform
        _camera.RotateAround(screenCenter, Vector3.up, Vector3.SignedAngle(pos2 - pos1, pos2b - pos1b, Vector3.up));
        _officeModel.CameraPos = _camera.position;
    }
    
    private Vector3 CreateRaycast(Vector3 direction)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Vector3 point = Vector3.zero;
        Ray ray = _officeModel.Camera.ScreenPointToRay(direction);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            point = hit.point;
        return point;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should make sure you are checking that there are 2 positions that are not starting or ending.

Also I wouldn't use raycasts to calculate your twirl angles, since that makes it awkward if the touch's ray suddenly misses the model, as well as other strange cases.

Be sure to notice the changes to `RotateAround`.

```
public void Execute()
{
    if (_officeModel.Camera.orthographic) return;

    _camera = _officeModel.Camera.transform;

    if (Input.touchCount < 2) 
    {
        return;
    }
    
    Touch touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);
    switch (touch0.touchPhase) {
        case TouchPhase.Stationary:
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            break;
        default: 
            return;
    }

    Touch touch1 = Input.GetTouch(1);
    switch (touch1.touchPhase) {
        case TouchPhase.Stationary:
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    var pos1 = touch0.position;
    var pos2 = touch1.position;
    var pos1b = touch0.position - touch0.deltaPosition;
    var pos2b = touch1.position - touch1.deltaPosition;

    // Get screen center transform
    var screenCenter = _officeModel.SelectedObject == null ? CreateRaycast(
            new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0)) 
            : _officeModel.SelectedObject.transform.position; 

    _camera.RotateAround(screenCenter, Vector3.up, 
             Vector3.SignedAngle(pos2b - pos1b, pos2 - pos1, Vector3.forward));

    _officeModel.CameraPos = _camera.position;
}

private Vector3 CreateRaycast(Vector3 direction)
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 point = Vector3.zero;
    Ray ray = _officeModel.Camera.ScreenPointToRay(direction);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        point = hit.point;
    return point;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, only now I managed to answer. Everything works perfectly!

Comment: @DavidBaranovsky Glad I could help, don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) if you found it helpful. It gives me some reputation points and helps people on the search panel with similar questions see that there's a helpful answer here.